# Changing to winter rim/tires

Tags: tires, winter

I have a 2018 Jetta SE with 205/55/HR16 tires.  Can I change winter/tire combo sized 215/55/r16?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are the rims the same thing between the winter and summer tires? Meaning are they the same backspacing and width? The tires should work just fine. They are a little bit wider (1 cm), but not much taller (maybe a few millimeters) so won't affect much.

Comment: Usually people go for a narrower tire for winter use - the theory being they cut through the slush etc better. And saw this once with a BMW 7 series - had winter tires fitted but the wide tires like 285 or so made it slip a lot!

Comment: The winter rims/tires are from a 206 Acura TL.  I went with a narrower tire since my TL had 235/45-17 all-season tires.  I bought separate rim/tire combo for the TL and wanted to see if I can use them in the Jetta

Comment: You may find the answer to this question helpful. https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/75051/downsizing-rims-from-14-to-13-what-is-the-optimal-tire-size/75053#75053  - https://www.tacomaworld.com/tirecalc